# Functional/acceptance тестирование мультиязычных сайтов?

Tags: php, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Есть ли какие-то лучшие практики создания приемочных и функциональных тестов для мультиязычных сайтов? С условием что может отличаться контент и отсутствовать перевод некоторых фраз/разделов и это хотелось бы проверять, но не дублировать тесты только ради переводов.

Если взять за пример Behat, как с самого начала стоит организовать среду тестирования?

Comment: А чем для тестов отличается "одноязычный" сайт от "мультиязычного"? В любом случае вы описываете ситуацию и проверяете на ожидаемый результат.

Comment: вопрос в организации самих тестов, хочется проверять и другие языки, но при этом не сильно дублировать тесты

Comment: я бы предложил тесты гонять на соответстиве ключей. А вот тестирование переводов, выделил бы в отдельный "проект".